# Get Value After Payment

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following object. How do I get the `email` value from it?

```
{
    "payment_method": "paypal",
    "payer_info": {
        "email": "example@domain.com",
        "first_name": "example",
        "last_name": "xxx",
        "payer_id": "12313213",
        "shipping_address": {
            "recipient_name": "Example",
            "id": "5435345",
            "line1": "1 SS ",
            "city": "San Jose",
            "state": "CA",
            "postal_code": "95131",
            "country_code": "US"
        },
        "phone": "4547567",
        "country_code": "US"
    }
}
```

Comment: is this a json object? or plain old php?

Comment: what is wrong with `array_name["payer_info"]["email"]` ?

Comment: it is json object. thanks for reply but it is solved myself. $array_name->payer_info->email